# How to wait for a process to terminate before it sends response

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, electron

I'm working with Electron and im using three pages. `Index.html` where I send a request, `Main.js` where the request is handled and `Page.js` where some long async function is created.

My problem is that I don't know how to make the main file to wait the `Page.js` process to finish before sending the response to the html page.

I tried to use a promise to send data back to the html, but I get an error because it said `.then()` function is not a function.

Index.html

```
document.querySelector('#formhomepage').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let date = document.getElementById("date-input").value;
        const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

        // send InputDate to main.js 
        ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', date )

        // receive output from main.js
        ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
          console.log(arg);
          document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = arg;

        });
        });
```

Main.js

```
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, inputDate) => {

  var excel_n1 = require('./page.js');

  excel_n1(inputDate).then(result => event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', result ) )
  .catch(error => {console.log("error")});

});
```

page.js

```
module.exports = async function(inputDate){
   // long await function with a lot of async and await
 }
```

Comment: where is your promise here? The problem is that in your `excel_n1` function you don't get a response?

Comment: i get the response but after some minutes. i have to wait before the main.js send the response to the Index.html. I tried to implement a promise but without success. The promise is implemented in the async function of the page.js file.

Comment: in the `index` at `ipcRenderer` you want to wait for the response from `Main` `excel_n1` function? which waits for the `page.js` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The excel_n1 variable is the function imported from the file page.js

Comment: does your `.then(result)` returns a result? in the `excel_n1` function

Comment: I don't know how to implement a Promise in this case, or if the Promise is the correct for this case. I think its better to think about a different solution. any suggestion ?

Comment: if you add your `page.js` maybe I can help you with the promise there, I will add a response as how it should look, your `page.js` if the answer is not working for you I will delete it afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `page.js` your promise should look something like the following

```
module.exports = function(inputDate){
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    try{
      ...your code
      resolve(response);
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e.message)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Promise does function argument does not need to be `async` especially if you do not plan to use `await` inside it. You are already returning a new Promise()

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini you are right, but the OP specified in the question that he uses a lot of `awaits` in the `page.js` that's why I put the `async` in there

Comment: Sorry. I've missed it